# Why android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" not working in Android 10 - API 29

Tags: android, android-10.0, scoped-storage

I have migrated my project compileSdkVersion from 28 to 29 and add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in my manifest, but file operations like downloading and file opening not working as it is in SDK 28

> **gradle file**

```
compileSdkVersion 29

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "in.example.app"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 90
    versionName "1.8.3"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

> **Manifest file**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="in.example.app">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SMS_FINANCIAL_TRANSACTIONS" />

<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:theme,android:allowBackup"
    tools:targetApi="n"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">

    <activity android:name=".ui.main.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="in.example.app.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>

</application>
```

> **file downloading code**

```
fun startDownloading(path: String, url: String): Long {
    return try {
        val downFileName = re.replace(url.substringAfterLast("/"), "")

        val downloadManager = context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
        val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
            request.setTitle(downFileName)
                .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(path, downFileName)
                .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
        downloadManager.enqueue(request)
    } catch (e: Exception){
        0
    }
}
```

- path should be a folder location in internal storage "/myapp/study materials/"
- url should be a file location url from the server

> **opening a file**

```
fun openFile(title: String, path: String){
    try {
        val newFile = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + path, title)

        val uri = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", newFile)
        } else{
            Uri.fromFile(newFile)
        }

        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, context.contentResolver.getType(uri))
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        val activities: List<ResolveInfo> = context.packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)
        val isIntentSafe: Boolean = activities.isNotEmpty()

        // Start an activity if it's safe
        if (isIntentSafe) {
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open With"))
        } else{
            MDToast.makeText(context, "No Application Found For Opening This File", MDToast.TYPE_INFO).show()
        }
    } catch (e : Exception){
        println("=============== ${e.message}")
    }

}
```

- path should be a folder location in internal storage "/myapp/study materials/"
- title should be the file name

> **file existance checking**

```
override fun checkFileExistence(title: String, path: String): Boolean {
    var flag = false
    try {
        val direct = File(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                    + path + title)
        flag = direct.exists()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
    }

    return flag
}
```

- path should be a folder location in internal storage "/myapp/study materials/"
- title should be the file name

I have added all code that is not working while updating to SDK 29, I want to download a file from the server and save it to an app-specific folder in internal storage also need to check if the file is already downloaded or not before downloading it. if it is already downloaded I need to open that file

Comment: can you please describe what exactly is not working? it is supposed to work exactly like before when you provide legacy storage as true

Comment: file downloading, file existence check, and file opening through the app not working

Comment: Downloading has nothing to do with requesting legacy external storage or not. So you might explain what you mean.

Comment: Further there is no code that tries to check the existence of a file or tries to open one.

Comment: In android 10 and 11, your best friend to work with files is file uri. `downloadManager.enqueue()` returns download id, which you can use to get uri via `downloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile(downloadId)`

Comment: `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(path, do...` You have not told us the value for path and filename. Put them in your code please so you show us what you do.

Comment: I have added all code that is not working while updating to SDK 29, I want to download a file from the server and save it to an app-specific folder in internal storage also need to check if the file is already downloaded or not before downloading it. if it is already downloaded I need to open that file

Comment: Your code seems good. I hope you remember to create that dir, when it's missing. Are any errors in logcat? You try to use `FileProvider` without registering his in manifest file, but I'm not sure it's a soution of your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry that was my bad I accidentally removed the file provider tag from manifest while removing unnecessary activities. actually, it was there and this code works perfectly fine with version 28, I'm also confused about what goes wrong

Comment: I also found one more thing this code works fine below android 10 phones even updated to SDK 29 but not on my android 10 device, problem is with android 10 devices only

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issues to those mentioned here. I found out that on Android 10, I have to check `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` even when file is already downloaded and I just need to open it.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 100)
}
```

Adding the check before any manipulation with the file fixed the "There was a problem parsing the package" error when opening the APK file.

**EDIT:**

I also found another (probably better) solution. Instead of using *external public storage*, I switched to *external storage* of the app:

```
downloadRequest.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(...)
```

and to access the file use

```
new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), mFileName);
```

instead of [now deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`

As a bonus there's no need to use `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in AndroidManifest.